# How to interrupt a waiting input of java

Tags: java, wait, interrupt

```
MainActivity.this.in = MainActivity.this.uart.getInputStream();
int re = in.read();
```

All of above is my part of code. I want to read a digit from peripheral device. if the waiting time is over 3 seconds. Stop! Then appear a warning information! But I don't know how to interrupt the wait.

Answer (score 0):

try set so_timeout to the corresponding socket like `Socket.setSoTimeout(3000L)` before you call `in.read();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!But I am not doing network programming.

Comment: Cursor cursor = DBHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this).select();
   ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   while (true) {
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
      .moveToNext()) {
     all.add(cursor.getInt(0));
    }
    label: for (int sstr : all) {
     final int forWarningInfo = sstr;
     try {
      out.write(hexStringToBytes(sendOrder[sstr - 1]));
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }